# GCC cosine optimization and sigbus

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a program that writes in some FPGA memory. When the program is compiled with optimizations (either O1, O2 or O3) it crashes with a bus error. However there is no crash when the program is compiled without optimizations.

Here is a minimal example which crashes:

```
void set_reg(const uint32_t *data)
{
    uint32_t val = data[0];
    dvm.write32(dac_map, 0, static_cast<uint32_t>(8192 * cos(val))); // crash
}
```

When I add volatile there is no more crash:

```
void set_reg(const uint32_t *data)
{
    volatile uint32_t val = data[0];
    dvm.write32(dac_map, 0, static_cast<uint32_t>(8192 * cos(val))); // no crash
}
```

If I remove the call to cos there is no problem.

This seems related to [GCC: program doesn't work with compilation option -O3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280069/gcc-program-doesnt-work-with-compilation-option-o3). When I add the flag `-ffloat-store` the program don't crash.

However, on the actual code which is more complicated, adding the flag `-ffloat-store` doesn't solve the problem.

I don't understand the kind of optimization GCC does and how this leads to a `SIGBUS`. If anyone could explain that, it would be useful for debugging.

Thank you.

---

NB:

1) GCC version is `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) 5.3.1 20160413`

2) The function `write32` is defined as

```
void write32(MemMapID id, uint32_t offset, uint32_t value) 
{
    ASSERT_WRITABLE
    *(volatile uintptr_t *) (GetBaseAddr(id) + offset) = value;
}
```

Comment: On the present architecture `uintptr_t` should be equal to `uint32_t`. If I just use `*(volatile uintptr_t) (GetBaseAddr(id) + offset) = value` I get an error `invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘uintptr_t {aka unsigned int}’)`.

Comment: oops, @user3719401, I forgot what `uintptr_t` was for--still, I would correct that type cast to `volatile uint32_t *` for consistency

Comment: Actually `GetBaseAddr` returns an `uintptr_t` since on some architecture the virtual memory addresses may be encoded with an `uint64_t` for example. Using `uint32_t` works here (and leads to the same problem), but it will break if the program is compiled on a 64 bits machine for example.

Comment: anyhow, is `data` pointing to memory-mapped FPGA memory? do you have any assembly code to compare the working and broken examples?

Comment: No `data` is 'normal' memory only `dac_map` is pointing to the FPGA memory. I don't have any assembly code, I can try to generate some but I will have to build the code in a small `main()`.

Comment: okay, please let me know when you have a self-contained example demonstrating the problem!

Comment: also let us know what you find out using a memory debugger/sanitizer like Valgrind